# redirecting page after login in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am quite newbie to codeigniter, I have login system to start with on site, and have 2 scenario:

1. If user is already logged in, and if clicks on url from other site(different domain), then it will redirect to given link.
2. If user is not logged in and click on link from other domain then he will first redirect to login page and then he will redirect again to clicked link.

now my first case works but not second, I tried setting a url in session like,

```
$array['login_redirect'] = current_url();

$this->session->set_userdata($array);
```

which is giving me correct url

but after login, session data shows login page url as value for `login_redirect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add condition to set current url.

for Example:

```
$current_url = current_url();
$login_url = 'www.test.com/login';   // Login url of current website

if($current_url != $login_url){
   $array['login_redirect'] = $current_url;
   $this->session->set_userdata($array);

}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried to vote up but its not allowing me, something regarding reputation.  <br/> well i am new too stackoverflow as well :-)

Comment: No worry man, Its my pleasure to solve your question.And I consider your appreciation is for my upvote.Thanks

Comment: @user1565283 : You can't upvote, but you can mark it correct. Search for right tick symbol just below downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

You can save current url in session when user is not logged in and don't do it when user is on login page - then you can read link from session and it will be link to last visited page.

Another solution is to save url to page in cookie when user clicks on link and then you can read it in PHP and redirect user to correct page.

Third solutiuon is to send this link via POST or GET when user is redirected to login page.

Comment: Thanks a million! I tried 1st option which is mentioned in Jay answers too and it worked!